# How can I loop through the systems.windows.forms.controls that has the control names in the sequential order?

Tags: vb.net

I have radio buttons named in the sequential order like "Jbtn1' to "Jbtn20". I am trying to name those buttons using set toolTip by using for loop.

```
 Dim toolTip1 As New ToolTip()
 For j As Integer = 1 To 20
   Dim pinInfo As String = "J2-" & j
   'Tried to convert the buttonName as Control , but got an error as 
   'Value of string cannot be converted to systems.windows.forms.control 
   Dim buttonName As Control = "Jbtn" & j
   toolTip1.SetToolTip(buttonName, pinInfo)
 Next
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You need something like Me.GroupBox1.Controls(buttonName).  We can't guess accurately at "GroupBox1".  Creating a user interface with twenty radio buttons is certainly best avoided, that's not very usable UI.

Comment: Tooltip is a component you can add to the form - why not do all this in the designer

Comment: @Plutonix I would like to do  it dynamically rather than entering for each form as I have many of those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Dim toolTip1 As New ToolTip()
For j As Integer = 1 To 20
    Dim pinInfo As String = "J2-" & j
    Dim control As Control = Me.Controls.Item("Jbtn" & j)
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(control, pinInfo)
Next
```

This code uses the form's `Controls` property to access controls on the form. You can lookup individual controls by their names using the indexer on `Controls`.

Comment: By the way, the names of the controls in the question are confusing. Initially, it says the names are "Jbtn1' to "Jbtn20", and then in the code it says "J2rbtn" & j which means "J2rbtn1" to "J2rbtn20"

Comment: I got an error saying as pinInfo is Null----Error is "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Value cannot be null.

Comment: Did you use the code as is? `pinInfo` is clearly defined.

Comment: My bad, it's the control name which is showing to be empty. PinInfo got some value to it. This line is showing the value as nothing - Dim control As Control = Me.Controls.Item("Jbtn" & j)

Comment: So, its the `control` that is `Nothing`? If so, the control was not found. Does the control sit on the form directly? Or does it live inside some container like a groupbox?

Comment: From the design side, Each button sits in a groupbox which contains all the other radio buttons next to it

Comment: Then simply call `groupBox1.Controls...` instead of `Me.Controls...` where `groupBox1` is the name of the groupbox control.

Comment: Are there multiple groupboxes?

Comment: Actually, I mean group box in the sense as all the buttons are grouped together sitting in a panel. I didn't used any groupbox

Comment: What is the name of the panel?

Comment: Panel name is "J2Panel"

Comment: Then use `J2Panel.Controls...`

Answer (score 0):

I would consider creating and adding the button dynamically rather then relying on the hard-coded name.

That said, you can use the ControlCollection(controlNameString) to find them by the name.

You can also use LINQ to Objects:

```
Dim radioButtons = From control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)
                   Where control.Name.StartsWith("Jbtn")

Dim toolTip = New ToolTip()

For Each radioButton In radioButtons
    toolTip.SetToolTip(radioButton, radioButton.Name.Replace("Jbtn", "J2-"))
Next
```

Comment: To make the code more readable here, consider splitting it into multiple lines.

Comment: I would use the query syntax on multiple lines, I didn't have Visual Studio to format it properly.

Comment: @ Uno. But, I need tooltip for all the 20 buttons. So, any other suggestions?

Comment: @Maddy This will apply it to all the buttons whose name starts with "Jbtn".

Comment: This is also a bit more extensible, if you add another controll JbtnX it will get a tooltip for free.